# Удаление атрибутов во всех html тегах, кроме <img> (php)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо очистить `html`-код от стилей, которые в него написал визуальный редактор.
Делаю так:

```
$handle = @fopen("new_item.htm", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {

        $buffer= fgetss($handle, 4096,'<img>,<title>,</title>,<table>,<tr>,</tr>,<td></td>,</table>'); 
        $html_clean= trim(preg_replace('/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i','<$1$2>',$buffer));
        echo($html_clean);      
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

В результате чего получаю требуемый вид кода, но с пустым содержимым тега      `<img>`.

Как правильно дописать регулярку, чтобы она еще и игнорировала содержимое тега      `<img>`?

Хочу получить что-то вроде:

```
<table>
<tr><td><img src="/path/img.jpg" width="100" height="400"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Может, так: `preg_replace('/<img\b[^<]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i','<$1$2>',$buffer)`?

Comment: Огромное спасибо, никогда не знал про (*SKIP). Все работает. Если вы добавите Ваш комментарий в качестве ответа, то я смогу закрыть вопрос :)

Comment: Используйте лучше нормальный HTML-парсер.

Comment: Не надо такое делать регулярками

Comment: Что есть нормальный HTML-парсер и почему не надо делать это регулярками?

Comment: Например такой парсер: [` Simple HTML DOM Parser`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Преимущества парсера в том, что он гарантирует правильность обработки (может даже исправлять мелкие погрешности в разметке, а pregExp упадёт), тогда как регулярки лишь **должны** работать.

Comment: спасибо за ссылку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно захватить целый тег `<img>` и восстановить с помощью обратной ссылки в шаблоне замены, но в PCRE есть и другой способ: использовать механизм пропуска совпадения.

```
preg_replace('/<img\b[^<]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i','<$1$2>',$buffer)
```

`<img\b[^<]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|` означает: найди `<img`, после `g` должен быть символ, отличный от буквы/цифры или `_`, затем 0+ символов, отличных от `<`, а затем `>`, а когда шаблон найдёт совпадение, всё это надо отбросить и продолжить поиск совпадений с того места, где закочнилось предыдущее совпадение.

Исключений может быть и больше, просто добавьте альтернативную группу: `/(?:ДРУГОЙ_ШАБЛОН_ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЯ|<img\b[^<]*>)(*SKIP)(*F)|ВАШ_ОСНОВНОЙ_ШАБЛОН/i`.